# How to POST using jquery and capture the reply in JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using this code:

```
function save() {
    // submit the dataform
    $.post(document.dataform.action, 
        $("#dataform").serialize(),
        function(reply) {
           //handle reply here
    });
}
```

This sends the right data to the server, but it arrives in $_GET. When I alter the server code to match I get the expected reply. There is a part of the query on the dataform.action. which I expected to arrive in $_GET.

How can I actually get the POST to send the data from the form so it arrives in $_POST, and thus avoid the size restrictions on GET?

I'm testing with Firefox, JQuery 9, and PHP 5.4.3

Thanks, Ian

Comment: How exactly are you calling that "save" function?

Comment: Via an on_Click event.  How could it matter?

Comment: It would matter if the `<form>` were still being submitted as part of the normal action of a form submit button, and its "method" were "GET" (which is the default).

Comment: Are you preventing the form from submitting? It's possible the original submit is GET thus messing up your POST

Comment: The form's method is POST. There is no submit button. However there IS a query on the post action.

Comment: Well `$.post()` uses the "POST" method unconditionally.  You can use Firebug to examine the HTTP headers for the actual transaction if you like.

Comment: And the data arrives with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST', but ALL the form data is in $_GET. I suspect the seriaize puts it there.

Comment: try `serializeArray()` instead http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ then `json_decode()` in php

Comment: From the browser, can you tell if the HTTP request has the parameters on the URL (like GET parameters) or in the request body (like a real form POST)?

Comment: Can't tell from the browser. PHP reports ALL the data in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

Comment: Ian, you *can* tell from the browser. Via Firebug or Chrome's developer tools, you can look at the actual HTTP request header.

Comment: i am pretty much sure @DavidNguyen spotted the issue.

Comment: serialize shouldn't change the method, if you do a print_r($POST); do you get anything?

Comment: $_POST is an empty array!

Answer (score 0):

$_GET takes parameter from query string so to have $_POST and $_GET just do this:

```
var action       = document.dataform.action;
var get_variable = "var1=v1&var2=v2..."; 
action = action+"?"+get_variable;
$.post(action, 
        $("#dataform").serialize(),
        function(reply) {
           //handle reply here
    });
```

Comment: document,dataform.actions ALREADY CONTAINS the query string. And I am quite happy for that to be sent urlencoded so it arrives in $_GET. What I need is fort the form *DATA* to be transmitted as if the form had been submitted as normal, and capture the reply

Answer (score 0):

```
function save() {
    // submit the dataform
    $.post(document.dataform.action, 
        { data: $("#dataform").serializeArray() })
    .done(function(reply) {
           //handle reply here
    });
}
```

then json_decode($_POST['data']); in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it! The correct method is

```
function save() {
    // submit the dataform
    $.ajax({
    url: document.dataform.action,
    data: new FormData(document.dataform),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(reply){
        if (reply.action) fetch('/content.php',reply.action);
        if (reply.content) document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=reply.content;
        if (reply.menu) document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=reply.menu;
        if (reply.status) document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=reply.status;
        calcSize();
        }
    });
}
```

This will however only work with browsers that support FormData - Chrome 7+, FF4.0+, IE 10+, Opera 12+ and Safari 5+
OK for my use-case ;) 
Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Credit to Ralph for his answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax